# Brother scanner and missing /dev/bus/usb entry?

Tags: linux-mint, usb, scanner

**APR 2015 UPDATE**: Scanning just worked! The update to Mint 17 (aka Ubuntu 14.04) did not make any difference, but the most likely explanation is that the recent update to Ubuntu 14.04.2 as the base distro fixed something.

(I haven't installed anything fresh from Brother, and I haven't touched any of the config files, in months. It is also the first time I tried scanning in months, so I don't think I can narrow anything down to self-answer this question. My kernel is "Linux len 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP")

---

I'm having awful trouble getting a DCP-7055 multi-function printer to work as a scanner with Mint 16. (My old flatbed scanner *was* working.) (I have printing working.) I've installed the Brother scanner drivers.

As a normal user, in simple scan, clicking scan immediately says `Failed to scan. Unable to connect to scanner`. If I run it as root it takes 15 seconds before saying `Failed to scan. unable to start scan`

I found [this comment](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/help-with-libusb-permissions-to-run-brother-mfc-j4510dw-scanner-on-ubuntu-13-10-a-4175501932/#post5154798) and for me `scanimage -L` says:

```
device `brother4:bus2;dev3' is a Brother DCP-7055 USB scanner
```

However `ls /dev/bus/usb/002/` only lists:

```
001  002
```

I.e. I think /dev/bus/usb/002/003 ought to exist, and doesn't, and that might explain everything?? But, now I've reached the end of my knowledge: what do I do about this?

**UPDATE:** Or maybe this is a red herring... after plugging the scanner into a different USB port, `scanimage -L` says:

```
device `brother4:bus2;dev1' is a Brother DCP-7055 USB scanner
```

But that exists:

```
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 128 Jul  2 22:16 /dev/bus/usb/002/001
```

Yet `simple-scan` gives exactly the same behaviour for both normal and root users.

Comment: Did you install the Brother drivers?

Comment: @FaheemMitha Yes (see first paragraph). In fact, once I finally had printing working, I also tried uninstalling them and installing them once more.

Comment: Ok. Sorry about my poor comprehension skills.

Comment: @FaheemMitha No problem. Using the latest Brother drivers was the key to getting printing working; the driver that Mint/CUPS suggested did not work.

Comment: Darren, did you do any configuration besides installing the drivers? My recollection was that there was at one and maybe more configuration step that had to be done. Can you list what additional steps you took besides actually installing the drivers? One thing I did was add the file `/etc/sane.d/dll.d/brother` containing just the word `brother4`. I'm pretty sure the brother drivers didn't add this.

Comment: An alternative is putting this in `/etc/sane.d/dll.conf`. The top of `dll.conf` has the following: "# Backends can also be enabled by configuration snippets under
# /etc/sane.d/dll.d directory -- packages providing backends should drop
# a config file similar to dll.conf in this directory, named after the package.". Also add yourself to the scanner group if you haven't already.

Comment: Note that the `brother4` may not be correct for you - it is probably model-dependent. Also, I'm not a member of the `scanner` group, but my Brother scanner still works, but I doing this over ethernet, and it might be necessary if the device is connected locally.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Thanks for the ideas. `brother4` was already in `/etc/sane.d/dll.conf` (and uncommented). I added myself to the `scanner` group but it made no difference.

Comment: OK, bear in mind you have to log in and out for the group to take effect. I think there was some initialization step I had to run after installation, I think using brsaneconfig4. (You could also try `brsaneconfig4 -q` to see what it says). Did you do anything like that? If I have any other ideas, I'll add a comment.